# Compute the volume of the body restricted with $z^2=x^2+y^2; z=0; (x^2+y^2)^2=2xy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

> Compute the volume of the body restricted with $z^2=x^2+y^2; z=0; (x^2+y^2)^2=2xy$ surfaces

I used cylindric coordinates and got:
$z=z; z=0; r=\sqrt{\sin 2t} $
So my problem is that I can’t find out bounds. Could you please explain in detail how can I do that without the picture

Comment: Does it say $z\ge 0$ or $z\le 0$? $z=0$ does not seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would say, why try to do it without the picture?  Pictures are really important to understand what's going on.  In this case, the plane curve $(x^2+y^2)^2 = 2xy$, or $r^2 = \sin 2\theta$, is a lemniscate.[image: lemniscate]
If $D$ is the region enclosed by that lemniscate, the volume you seek is
$$
    V = \iint_D \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dA
$$
To simplify, first let's just use the symmetry to integrate over the first quadrant and double it.  Then we don't have to worry about $\sin 2t$ going negative.  We can say $r = \sqrt{\sin 2\theta}$ on this region.  So
\begin{align*}
    V &= 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\sqrt{2\sin 2\theta}}(r)r\,dr\,d\theta
    \\&= \frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left.r^3\right|_{r=0}^{r=\sqrt{2\sin 2\theta}} \,d\theta
    \\&= \frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{3/2}2\theta\,d\theta
\end{align*}
The integrand cannot be antidifferentiated in elementary terms, however.  [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%202%2F3%20sin(2theta)%5E(3%2F2)%20from%20theta%3D0%20to%20pi%2F2) says the answer is about 0.582679.

If the surface under which this solid lies were different, we might have an elementary integral.  For instance, if it were $z=x^2+y^2$ instead of $z^2=x^2+y^2$, the sine exponent would be $2$ instead of a fraction, and we could integrate that with a trig identity.